# Probability of obtaining at least one head in $k$ independent tosses of a coin

Tags: probability

> In each of $k$ independent tosses of a coin, it lands on heads with
> probability $\alpha$. Write an expression for the proability of
> obtaining at least one head.

### attempt

P(at least one head) = 1 - P(at most one head)

Hence, we want

\begin{align*}
1 - P(\text{no heads}) - P(\text{1 head}) &= 1 - (1-\alpha)^k - \alpha(1-\alpha)^{k-1}\\
\end{align*}

Is this a correct expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{at least one head} = \text{one head or more}$, so $P(\text{at least one head}) = 1 - P(\text{no heads})$, which is just:

$$1 - (1-\alpha)^k$$